# java graphics drawString error font when deploy on server

Tags: java, graphics

I have a problem with drawString() method and I don't know how to solve.
This is my code to drawString on exists image:

```
  final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(templateFile);
  Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
  g.drawString("Đà Nẵng", 950, 126);
  g.drawString("\u0110\u00E0 N\1EB5ng", 994, 166);
```

On my local (window 10), this is ok
[image]

But when deploy on server (solaris 5.10), this is fail
[image]

Is there a font missing on server?

Thank for any help

Comment: maybe missing locale, isn't it ?...on my server: locale -a print C POSIX iso_8859_1